# Pandas Correlation Matrices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a large DataFrame; the values of all columns are floating point numbers, and the indices are of type DatetimeIndex. For example, here is the first part of my DataFrame:

```
           col0 col1 col2 col3 col4 ...
2035-10-30  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...   
2035-10-31  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...
2035-11-01  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...
2035-11-02  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0 ...
    ...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ...
```

For every single element in my list of indices (i.e. every single date), I want to find the correlation matrix for the last 1000 rows of the DataFrame using the `.corr()` method, as demonstrated in the code below:

```py
for d in df.index:
    cor_mat = other_df[:d].tail(1000).corr()
```

In the code above, `df` and `other_df` both have the same dimensions and the same indices.

What I currently have is extremely slow, because the dimensions of my DataFrame are very big. How can I vectorize this operation, or otherwise make it more efficient? I've tried playing with the `.rolling()` method, but I haven't been able to get the right answer yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

what problems you having with  Rolling method ? you can use it like this to compute the correlation matrix for every date.

```
window_size = 1000
corr_matrices =df.rolling(window_size).corr()
corr_matrices_last =  corr_matrices.groupby(level=0).tail(1)
corr_matrices_last = corr_matrices_last.dropna()
```